# Database schema for slightly different entities

Tags: database, database-design

I need to create a database that should store such entities as movies. Application logic will collect movies from different external APIs and store them in a database. The problem is the different APIs provide slightly different data. For example:

API 1:

- List item
- id: int
- title: string
- actors: array

API 2:

- List item
- id: int
- title: string
- rating: int
- actors: array

API 3:

- List item
- id: int
- title: string
- actors: array
- age_restriction: int

And so on. So my question is how should I store these entities in the database? I see the next approaches:

1. Create a separate table for each external API. How can I generate a
   unique ID for an entity between separate tables in this approach?
2. Create one wide table with all possible fields.
3. Create one table with general fields, other fields move to separate tables.

Which pros and cons in the above ways?

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Option 3 is a better choice.

Comment: This is a faq. Before considering posting please read the manual & google any error message or many clear, concise & precise phrasings of your question/problem/goal, with & without your particular strings/names & site:stackoverflow.com & tags; read many answers. If you post a question, use one phrasing as title. See [ask] & the voting arrow mouseover texts.